# Geometric Distribution - Expected number of rolls of a die before a value occurs

Tags: r

Say I want to calculate the expected number of rolls of a die before a particular value is rolled, let's say a 5. I know this involves geometric distribution. Is there an R function that can calculate this?

Comment: Gee, why didn't I think of that? I've been there. None of those functions, as near as I can tell, solve this particular problem directly (without additional calculations). Don't be so quick to downvote questions.

Comment: This is a basic math/stats question, not a programming question. The answer is basically here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1120473. It's a geometric distribution so the mean is 1/p where p=prob of success. Since you want a 5, your chance of success is 1/6 (there are 6 numbers on the die and 1 is a 5) so the expected number of tosses is 6.

Comment: @MrFlick - Did you read my question closely? I wasn't asking the statistical calculations to work this out. I was asking if there was an R function to calculate this. So, it is a programming question.

Comment: So you were asking if there was a function that would divide one number by another number? Because that's how you answer this question.

Comment: Wouldn't that be an amazing world? Where people understood math and statistics well enough to feel confident doing simple problems in their head without asking a computer to do "magic" they don't understand to get the answer? Computers are great at doing very fast calculation but it's up to the humans to decide what problems to offload and which problems they can solve on their own (more smartly than a computer could).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a sum of an infinite series. We basically need to model every scenario - that is we need to sum the expected value of getting a 5 on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc rolls. To do this we can use a simple sum (not infinite, but a large number to basically get "close" to infinite behavior). The code to do that in R is:

```
x<-100
rolls<-0
for (i in 1:x){
  rolls<-rolls + (5/6)^(i-1)*(1/6)*i
}
```

Putting this code into plain english we have:

- Sum the first 100 rolls
- For each roll, n, the probability of a 5 *on that roll* = (probability of not getting a 5 on all rolls leading up to roll **n**) * (probability of 5 on roll **n**)
- The probability of not getting a 5 on all rolls leading up to roll **n** = (prob of not 5^(n-1)) = (5/6^(n-1))
- Probability of a 5 on any given roll is 1/6

Finally now that we have the probability of a 5 on any given roll, **n** (which is just (5/6^n-1 * 1/6), then we can multiply this probability by the roll number to get the expected value of each roll. This gives us the equation seen in the code.

Looking at the result we see that is converges to 6:

```
rolls
[1] 5.999999
```

You can probably solve this without doing any programming, but its been a while since I did that type of math.